# custom attribute not found in my custom View

Tags: android, styles, android-custom-view, custom-attributes

I have this line in my account_particle.xml layout

```
            android:padding="?attrs/disc_padding"
```

this attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="AccountParticle">

    <attr name="text_margin_start" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="disc_padding" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="disc_imageViewSize" format="reference"/>


  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and this styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.ap.header" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="disc_padding">@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_start</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Theme.ap.list_item" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="disc_padding">@dimen/account_menu_account_list_item_avatar_margin_start</item>



      </style>
```

Why do i get this compilation error?

```
 error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'padding' with value '?attrs/disc_padding').
```

AccountParticle

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `android:padding="?attrs/disc_padding"`

with `android:padding="?attr/disc_padding"` or `android:padding="?disc_padding"`